# How to map IDictionary that has a IList value?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Using NHibernate, how can I map the following scenario:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual IDictionary<Project, IList<Role>> ProjectAssignments { get; set; }
}
```

In the database I have separate tables for `User`, `Project` and `Role` and a fourth table for the relationship.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - from [Ayende's blog discussing <map>](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/03/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-ltmapgt.aspx)

> I would like to point out that I have still not covered all the options for <map/>, there
>   are even more options (Although, IDictionary<K, IList<V >> is not something that is 
>   possible to map, for the problematic SQL statements that would be required to do so).

You'll need some intermediary entity/component. I'd probably have a ProjectAssignment entity to break up the nary association between User, Project and Role - it will probably grow extra attributes as time goes on (say you want to track changes to the assignments over time, so it gets `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties).

Something like:

```
public class User {
  // ... other attributes etc.
  public virtual ISet<ProjectAssignment> Assignments {get;set;}
}

public class Project {
  // ... other attributes etc.
  public virtual ISet<ProjectAssignment> Assignments {get;set;}
}

public class Role {
  // ... other attributes etc.
}

public class ProjectAssignment
{
  public virtual Int64 {get;set;}
  public virtual User User {get;set;}
  public virtual Project Project {get;set;}
  public virtual Role Role {get;set;}
  // ... other attributes etc.
}
```

I'd just map the ProjectAssignment as a persistent class in its own right, and the User.Assignments collections as a normal one-to-many of whatever flavour. Finally, I'd add a method to extract the details into a dictionary (or probably an ILookup if you're using Framework v3.5): something like:

```
ILookup<Project, Role> GetRolesByProject() {
    return Assignments.ToLookup(x => x.Project, x => x.Role);
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about how everything is going to fit. Can you please give me an example of what the intermediary entity is going to look like and how I would map it?