# How can I map a dictionary of string and IList<string> in fluent nhibernate?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a class which contains an collection of values structured as a dictionary with keys as string and each element a list of strings.

How can I map this as a separate table without having to define an additional class?

I've tried the following code but can't get it to work.

Class

```
public class User
{
  property virtual Guid Id {get; set; }
  property IDictionary<string, List<string>> Rights;
}
```

Mapping

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
  public UserMap()
  {
    Id(p => p.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
    HasMany(p => p.Rights).
                 Table("Rights").
                 KeyColumn("Key").
                 Element("Right").
                 AsMap<string>("Rights");
```

Currently I'm fumbeling in darkness as to how I can get this to work. It seems easy to map a Dictionary< string, string> but maybe its impossible to map a Dictionary< string, List< string>> in this fashion?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to cheat a bit and use a backing field that still uses the `IDictionary<string, string>`, but exposes it as an `IDictionary<string, List<string>>`.

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    // Map this one
    protected internal virtual IDictionary<string, string> RightsInternal { get; set; }

    // Use this one
    public virtual IDictionary<string, List<string>> Rights
    {
        get { return RightsInternal.ToDictionary(_ => _.Key, _ => _.Value.Split('|').ToList()); }
        set { RightsInternal = value.ToDictionary(_ => _.Key, _ => string.Join("|", _.Value)); }
    }
}
```

Make sure you only map `Id` and `RightsInternal` (you can map `protected internal` properties with NHibernate as explained [here](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Mapping-private-properties#use-internals)).

The clean solution would be to expand this association into OneToMany relationships or go even further and use a NoSQL database which provide excellent support for key-value storage.

Also, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1171087/3570096).